# Loading one big entity or many small entities

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a WPF application, I use Entity Framework for database operations and then I create some ObservableCollections from given User's entities in MainViewModel.

```
 public new async Task<UserDto?> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            User? user = await _databaseContext.Users
                          .Include(x => x.MovieUrls)
                          .Include(x => x.Theme)
                          .Include(x => x.Samples).ThenInclude(x => x.Image)
                          .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.Needles)
                          .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.Yarns)
                          .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.ProjectStatus)
                          .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.PatternPdf)
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            return user is null ? null : new UserDto(user.Id, user.Nickname, user.Email, user.Projects, user.Samples, user.MovieUrls, user.Theme);
        }
```

It is important that all those entities will change often as user will add/update/remove samples, projects etc., so I need to update the entities and then send query to get refreshed data.

Should it be more efficient to separate it into more smallers queries for each Entity that I want to convert to ObservableCollection?

So that would be:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MovieUrl>> GetMovieUrls(int userId)
public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(int userId)
public async Task<IEnumerable<Sample>> GetSamples(int userId)
```

Comment: You might want to `.AsSplitQuery()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

Comment: Should it be more efficient than many manually created queries?
I think it would be better to maintain for me to create query for each entity than whole big User object, but what about performance or database load

Comment: If you actually want to fetch all that data, then split queries should help. But, the question of how much data to query, and how to display that data would depend on how you design your application. Which is beyond the scope of an SO question.